# Need JS code to change the specific filename to a different filename in a link that is associated with list items on a page

Tags: javascript, hyperlink, sharepoint-2013

I have a lookup page that has a list of users and a link that is associated to those users that actually will do a search in an Excel document for an occurrence of their name in the spreadsheet.  The spreadsheet is a RACI spreadsheet if anyone cares.

I need to have a lookup for three different RACI spreadsheets, and instead of adding three variables to the SP list, I would like to use JS to change the filename in the calculated field that displays the Link to use a different filename for a given page.

Example change the Link from

href="https://xxxx.gov/hc/teams/MES/_vti_bin/ExcelRest.aspx/MMIS/**MMIS DDI RACI.xlsx**/model/Ranges('SearchedRACI')?$format=html&Ranges(%27NameFilter%27)=Hamtgmes, Abbey M">See RACI

to

href="https://xxxx.gov/hc/teams/MES/_vti_bin/ExcelRest.aspx/MMIS/**MMIS%20Maintenance%20and%20Operation%20RACI.xlsm**/model/Ranges('SearchedRACI')?$format=html&Ranges(%27NameFilter%27)=Hamtgmes, Abbey M">See RACI

There are about 10 or so records that display and as the user moves through this list (there could be hundreds or records and user uses the arrows to "page" through the list), I would need the links updated each time the data is refreshed.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your description, you are attempting to change the hyperlink created within a calculated column based on the page the list view web part is displayed on.

Try using this formula in your calculated column with a returned data type of number.  This will allow the HTML to be rendered.  Also, be sure to update the 'pageA.aspx', fileURL, and File Link placeholders.

Calculated Column Formula:

```
="<img src='/_layouts/images/blank.gif' onload=""{"&"var url = _spPageContextInfo.serverRequestPath.split('/');"&"var page = url[url.length - 1];"&"var link = '';"&"if (page === 'pageA.aspx') {link = '<a href=\'fileURL\'>File Link</a>'}"&"if (page === 'pageB.aspx') {link = '<a href=\'fileURL\'>File Link</a>'}"&"if (page === 'pageC.aspx') {link = '<a href=\'fileURL\'>File Link</a>'}"&"this.parentNode.innerHTML= link;"&"}"">"
```